# Site crashing when activating new site feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, reusable-workflow

I am trying to import a reusable workflow to use in a different site than it was designed on. I am able to activate it in solutions with no problem, but when I try to activate the feature in the site features page the site crashes. Is there any reasons why this is happening? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: So this is a custom solution that you added? Did you test this in another environment?

Comment: Yes I tested this on another site.

Comment: So it worked out there and doesn't work on production?

Comment: It worked on the original site, once I save it as a template and moved it to another site is when I have a problem

Comment: when u said another site, is it another tenant or site collection with in the same tenant. there could be chances that serveral features could be missing from tenant to tenent as MicroSoft rolls out the features based on the first release settings.